# Choose Random xml entry once per load with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to choose from a number of entries in an xml file and show them on a webpage. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong... does anyone have suggestions?

Thank you for your time :-)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var numLow = 1;
    var numHigh = 3;
    var adjustedHigh = (parseFloat(numLow))+1;
    var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*adjustedHigh)+parseFloat(numLow); 

$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '../xml/testad.xml',
dataType: 'xml',
success: function(xml_list) {

var xmlArr = [];

$(xml_list).find('entry').each(function(i) {
  var xml_id = $(this).attr('id');
  if(xml_id == numRand) return; //keep going if this wasn't the right ID

    var xml_name        = $(this).find('name').text();
    var xml_link        = $(this).find('link').text();
    var xml_url         = $(this).find('url').text();
                      // Add matched items to an array
    xmlArr += '<div class="ad"><a href="';
    xmlArr += xml_url;
    xmlArr += '" alt="'
    xmlArr += xml_name;
    xmlArr += '"><img src="';
    xmlArr += xml_link;
    xmlArr += '" /></a></div>';

}); // end each loop

 //Append array to adviewer div (this way is much faster than doing this individually for each item)

    $(xmlArr).appendTo('#adviewer');
    $('#adviewer').show();
}
});
</script>
```

Above looks like it 'should' work but it doesn't actually select an random entry...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var numLow = 1;
var numHigh = 3;
var adjustedHigh = (parseFloat(numLow))+1;
var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*adjustedHigh)+parseFloat(numLow);

$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '../xml/testad.xml',
dataType: 'xml',
success: function(xml_list) {

var xmlArr = [];

$(xml_list).find('entry').each(function() {

 var xml_id       = $(this).attr('id');

 var xml_name      = $(this).find('name').text();
 var xml_link   = $(this).find('link').text();
 var xml_url   = $(this).find('url').text();
       // Add matched items to an array
 xmlArr += '<div id=: '
 xmlArr += xml_id;
 xmlArr += '"class="ad"><ahref="';
 xmlArr += xml_url;
 xmlArr += '" title="'
 xmlArr += xml_name;
 xmlArr += '"><img class="ad" src="';
 xmlArr += xml_link;
 xmlArr += '"></a></div>';

 if(id == numRand).appendTo(div +' class="adviewer"');
 }

}); // end each loop

</script>
```

Comment: It might help if you indicated the symptoms.  Syntax errors, incorrect output, etc.  Also, have you tried debugging with Firebug and verified the responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* what you're after is something like this:

```
$(xml_list).find('entry').each(function(i) {
  var xml_id = $(this).attr('id');
  if(i != numRand) return; //keep going if this wasn't the right ID
  var xml_name = $(this).find('name').text(),
      xml_link = $(this).find('link').text(),
      xml_url  = $(this).find('url').text();

  var div = $('<div />' { 'id': xml_id, 'class': 'ad' });
  div.append($('<a />', { 'href': xml_url, 'title': xml_name }));
  div.append($('<img />', {'class': 'ad', 'src': xml_link }));
  div.appendTo('div.adviewer');
}); // end each loop
```

There are currently a few syntax errors, mainly with this:

```
if(id == numRand).appendTo(div +' class="adviewer"');
```

[`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) is called on a jQuery object to append to something, the selector for `<div class="adviewer">` would look like `div.adviewer`, like I have above.

The rest of the changes center around switching to the [`$(html, props)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) DOM element creation method to property handle encoding and such (if you have a quote in anything for example).  Also `id` is undefined in your question/code...I'm *assuming* you meant index here, if you didn't then change the `if(i != numRand)` to be `if(xml_id == numRand)` instead, that'll compare to the ID from the XML.

Comment: if(xml_id == numRand) return; was my intention.

Comment: What is the easiest way to choose a random number based on number of <entries> within the xml?

Comment: @fchrisb - That depends, are the entries sequentially numbered, or are they all over the place?  It seems like choosing a random index of `<entry>` element would be an easier approach.

Comment: @fchrisb - Here's an example of how to get a random position, so it'd be a random `<entry>` used: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Nk2tq/ It's not a working example (throws a few errors), but plugged into your existing code with the XML it should work.

Comment: @Nick - Not able to make that code work... not sure why. I posted what I have within the script brackets on the test page at your jsfiddle... check it out and let me know if you see any reason why it shouldn't be working. BTW, Thanks a bunch for your feedback.

Comment: @fchrisb - You still have the `.each()` loop on there, make sure it's not inside a loop, like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Nk2tq/5/

Comment: @Nick - I got a kinda hybrid working... but I am so thankful for your help. You really don't know how much gratitude is coming at you right now, bro.

Comment: @Nick - BTW, I just wanted to share... Math.floor works much better than Math.ceil... With Math.ceil I could never get the first entry to load and often a 'blank' entry would load nothing. With Math.floor... I consistently got all three entries to load randomly, of course.